# prevent upload php script to be executed

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a system where user pay for support, each user have a folder. I have many (like 200+) sub folderד in my website, each of these needs the CSS, images, JS etc...

I also create folders every week for new users when they register, each user can upload PHP script or JS script or images. (screenshot of their problem)

My problem is: in my `/.htacess`, I have a rule that checks for PHP script and redirects to the proper page e.g. `site.com/user/page` will go to `site.com/user/page.php`

What I want to do is prevent the user from breaking the system, for example by:

`site.com/user/upload/test` will go to his `test.php` and run it.

How can I prevent these kind of attacks?

Answer (score 23):

Block access to PHP files in you htaccess, put this file inside the folder you want to block files:

```
<Files ^(*.php|*.phps)>
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
</Files>
```

Or in root .htaccess file you can:

```
<Directory ^user/upload>
    <Files ^(*.php|*.phps)>
        order deny,allow
        deny from all
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Will block access to all php files inside the user/upload folder, even if mod_rewrite is used.

But, if you want to keep the .php files accessible for download and don't want they execute it, you can use this on .htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch "(.+)$">
    ForceType text/plain
</FilesMatch>
```

All files in the folder will return as `text/plain`. You can bind this in the Directory tag to get a similar result of deny access from the second example.

You also can chose the file extensions you want to delivery as `text/plain`:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php|pl|py|jsp|asp|htm|shtml|sh|cgi.+)$">
    ForceType text/plain
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Thanks that really helped. What about C files, is the above list (of FilesMatch) is complete. I am terrified

Comment: is a Regular Expression, you can match anything you want. Your server will not execute C file by the browser, it will delivery as data file (download). If you talking about the source, you can deny or allow access for it. If you want ANY file be downloadable as text, you can put `"(.+)$" as your regular expression and any file, I said ANY file, in the folder will be text/plain

Comment: Thanks, that is just fine, i will use "(.+)$
Thanks

Comment: Just a quick note: If you are trying to block users from executing php shells, then don't use this method! What if someone uploads a .htaccess file?

Comment: Would be good to only permit the extensions that would you may use, or you also can block .htaccess uploading and access is deny by default in apache 2 configs.

Comment: when I add "<Directory ^wp-content/uploads>" on my webroot .htaccess it crashes my whole site tho, but "<Files ^(*.php|*.phps)>" on a separate htaccess under wp-content/uploads/ works perfectly for me

Comment: This approach is a little bit flawed - if an attacker uploaded a file called foobar.jpg.php, it would be executable. As if it was named foobar.php5. The best idea is to do `<Files (*.php|*.phps|*.php5)$>`

Comment: @CJxD it depends on your higher level configuration, anyway this is an example how to do it, if you want to cover more options, just add or remove from your conditional. The answer still correct.

Comment: How to restrict more folders like root/images, root/uploads, root/contents etc?

Comment: This also prevents my root folder php files to execute. How to enable them but disallow .php files present in /upload folder?

Comment: @RNKushwaha you can use the .htaccess only inside the upload folder to block it, or specify in the root folder only the folder what you want to not execute or deny files.

Comment: I've also had to add `RemoveHandler cgi-script .pl` for it to work, otherwise  my apache 2.4.10 with suexec still insisted on executing `.pl` files instead of showing them in browser as text...

Answer (score 4):

Please remember that Apache might have more extensions to handle by PHP type handler, and it indeed has. Here is the .htaccess content that works fine for our server.

```
<FilesMatch "(?i)\.(php5|php4|php|php3|php2|phtml|pl|py|jsp|asp|htm|shtml|sh|cgi)$">
    ForceType text/plain
</FilesMatch>
```

It is working fine for us.

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is: in my /.htacess, I have a rule that checks for PHP script and redirects to the proper page e.g. site.com/user/page will go to site.com/user/page.php

Why not just create the users page as site.com/user/page/index.php ?

> site.com/user/upload/test will go to his test.php and run it

Then your rewrite rule is wrong - but you didn't show us what it is. Also your code for handling file uploads is wrong - and its not just PHP which is the problem - you could be acting as a mule site for all sorts of malware.

When allowing users to upload content, you should **never** store it in such a way that it is directly addressable by the webserver (except maybe for very large files of very specific and VERIFIED file types - such as videos). All access should be mediated by a control script (which *may* set the mime type and filename for the content it channels).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had an idea before you redirect to test.php, you redirect to a page that will verify that the code belongs to X user, if assigned, following the routine and redirects, if you do not belong, fires a 404

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I misunderstood the question.
I would think the best way to prevent these attacks from happening would be to save the files as .php.txt or something, so it's non-executable.

But print out the file's contents via `f_open();` or `file_get_contents();`

If this is not what you are looking for, can you provide information about what your website does, exactly?

Comment: im sorry i dont understand what you mean